# "Пишущая машинка" или "печатная машинка"?

Tags: фразеология

Всегда был уверен, что правильно говорить и писать **"пишущая машинка"**, но в последнее время постоянно встречаю в устной и письменной речи словосочетание **"печатная машинка"**. Может быть, "печатная машинка" уже вытеснила" "пишущую машинку" и стала нормативным словосочетанием?

Comment: Матвей, вот лекция Максима Крангауза.В ней он подробно рассказывает о печатной и пишущей машинки.  [Максим Кронгауз.
«На смерть пишущей машинки»](http://arzamas.academy/mag/227-kronhaus)

Comment: Очень интересная лекция. Спасибо, Серж!

Comment: Был термин "пишущая машинка", да приказал долго жить.Туда ему и дорога. Ведь бессмыслица была полная: "Печатать на пишущей машинке".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изначально "пишущая" (отсюда название заводов по изготовлению машинок: ПишМаш), потом названия стали взаимозаменяемыми. Поначалу различие между "пишущей" и "печатной" (см., например, у Ильфа и Петрова в "Золотом теленке") было различием между портативной машинкой и печатным станком ("печатная машина").

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Павел!

Comment: Пожалуйста, Матвей.